# Can we see users reading the chat transcripts?

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

Users who want to read chat messages can either enter the room they were posted in or view its transcript. Only the former category show up in the room's sidebar. Is there any way we can see that people are reading a room's transcript, and/or add them to the sidebar?

Comment: Ok with minus vote if i asking anything wrong. but expect reason for minus vote so i can improve my question.please it's request

Comment: Why do you want to be able to see who's reading the transcript? What purpose would this serve?

Comment: actually some user are reading transcripts and copy past linked of messages in other chat room so i just want to know who are reading the chat transcripts.

Comment: You haven't really provided a reason for this information. What does it matter that chat messages are copied into other rooms? And if they are, you can tell at least one user who was reading the transcript. In the meantime, just assume that _everyone_ is reading the transcripts _at all times_.

Comment: Chat transcripts are public just like questions and answers on a Stack Exchange site are public. You cannot see who reads that, no.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, we normal users (and I assume this goes for moderators as well) can't see who got served a page to their device. Only devs or sysops could know.

And I want to keep it that way. I use the feature to check on SPAM posts and I don't want to disturb the room by entering it.

You might have overlooked anonymous users. They can read the transscript as well, do you expect something to be shown in the sidebar as well for them?

Suppose we do know who is reading the transscript, for what purpose are you going to use that fact?